# Using IntersectionObserver to detect element with 100vh is fully visible

Tags: javascript, html, intersection-observer

I need to immediately block scroll as soon as a div is fully visible.
The tricky part is that .stopDiv has 100vh height.
I tried using IntersectionObserver to detect it.

```
    const stopDiv = document.querySelector('.stopDiv');

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([e]) => {
        window.addEventListener('mousewheel', defaultScrollHandler, { passive: false });
        window.addEventListener('wheel', defaultScrollHandler, { passive: false });
        window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', defaultScrollHandler, { passive: false });
    },
    {threshold: 1}
    );

    observer.observe(stopDiv);

    function defaultScrollHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        return false;
    }
```

The problem is the event is never called, unless the scroll perfectly stop when the div top is exactly on the beginning of the viewport (very low chance). How can I manage it?

Comment: Fully visible would mean that the top of the scrolling element would need to be at the top edge of the viewport since it's 100vh. So since you don't want it to stop exactly at the top edge of the viewport, where exactly do you want the scrolling element to stop at?.

Comment: No, it's what I want, to stop exactly at the top edge of the viewport. But the scroll almost never stop exactly there, and that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Observing an intersection of a target element that is the same size of viewport is not feasible using default values of the `options` Object (see the comments in the HTML of the example below for details, and read this [article](https://uploadcare.com/blog/intersection-observer-guide/) as well).

In the example, scroll up in order to bring `<section class="target lime">` into the viewport. Once `<mark class="target">` (located at the bottom of `section.target.lime`) triggers an intersect,  is assigned className `.stopped` turning it's background to "tomato" red and disabling vertical scrolling with `overflow-y: hidden`. There's a button in the left top corner that toggles IO on all `.target` for demo purposes.

***Details are commented in example***

### ```js
// Reference <html>
const root = document.documentElement;
// Collect all ".target" into a NodeList
const targets = document.querySelectorAll(".target");
/**
 * Define an options Object to pass through an IO instantiation.
 * Both entries are default:
 */
const options = {
  // Scrolling ancestor element. null is viewport
  root: null,
  /**
   * Minimal portion of an observed element is required to trigger IO.
   * 1.0 = the entire observed element.
   */
  threshold: 1.0
};

/**
 * Callback function that IO will call every time it's triggered.
 * If an entry (aka observed element or target) is intersecting...
 * ...add ".stopped" to <html> -- which will disable scrolling...
 * ...by assigning "overflow-y: hidden" to <html>
 */
const callback = (entries, IO) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      root.classList.add("stopped");
    }
  });
}

// Instantiate an IO Object
const IO = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
// Assign .observe() method to each ".target"
targets.forEach(section => IO.observe(section));

/**
 * DEMO PURPOSES -- NOT REQUIRED
 * A <button> that toggles IO off and on.
 */
document.querySelector("button").onclick = toggleIO;

function toggleIO(e) {
  this.classList.toggle("on");
  this.classList.toggle("off");
  if (this.matches(".off")) {
    targets.forEach(section => IO.unobserve(section));
    root.classList.remove("stopped");
  } else {
    targets.forEach(section => IO.observe(section));
  }
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}


/**
 * <html> is the root element used for scrolling viewport
 */

:root {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font: 2ch/1.15 "Segoe UI";
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

mark {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5.5vh;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}


/**
 * className added to <html> in order to disable scrolling
 */

.stopped {
  background: tomato;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.cyan {
  background: cyan;
}

.lime {
  background: lime;
}

.gold {
  background: gold;
}


/**
 * DEMO PURPOSES -- NOT REQUIRED
 * A <button> that toggles IO off and on.
 */

button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 2vh;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -6ch;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.off::before {
  content: "";
}

.off:hover::after {
  content: "IO Off";
}

.on::before {
  content: "";
}

.on:hover::after {
  content: "IO On";
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  DEMO PURPOSES -- NOT REQUIRED
  A <button> that toggles IO off and on.
-->
<button class="on"></button>
<!-- An unobserved <section> -->
<section class="cyan"></section>
<!-- 
  Target <section>s are full height of viewport. 
  The default value for option.threshold is 1.0 which means
  that the entire target must be visible to intersect.
  1.0 is problematic for an element that is always obscured 
  at viewport edges. 
  Either: 
    - use a lower options.threshold
    - offset the root to target by options.rootMargin
    - use a small target element at the bottom of a target <section>
      if scrolling up and vice versa.
    The latter technique is used (<mark class="target">)
  -->
<section class="target lime">
  <mark class="target"></mark>
</section>
<section class="target gold">
  <mark class="target"></mark>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you time. Unfortunately also the solution doesn't work. As you can see from the screenshot (https://ibb.co/6ybWVRp) taken from your example, there is a portion of the yellow section visible and so the green section is not fully visible inside the viewport.